# SQL select from a combine table

Tags: mysql

there are tables with same prefix which have the same primary key

for example

```
my_table_1                             my_table_2 

name  data_0  data_1  ...  data_9      name  data_10  data_11  ...  data_19
jack  1.0     2.0     ...  1.5         jack  7.0      3.0      ...  2.5
amy   0.7     5.01    ...  1.7         amy   0.77     5.011    ...  1.97
.                                      .
.                                      .
.                                      .
```

but i cant use 
`SELECT * FROM my_table_1, my_table_2 WHERE data_0 >= 1 AND data_11 > 3;`

is there any method to do that?

Comment: you need JOIN https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Answer (score 2):

One option without knowing the data in your example is to use `UNION`

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_1 WHERE (table_1 filter here)
UNION
SELECT * FROM my_table_2 WHERE (table_2 filter here)
```

The only thing is that the columns will have to be named or aliased the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use JOIN, you say both PK are the same you can use this.

```
SELECT * FROM my_table_1 JOIN my_table_2 ON my_table_1.PK = my_table_2.PK
```

More info: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp